# Determining how to make 7 wire DC motor run?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor, wiring

I have got these motor. I wanted to make it run. It has 7 wires.

The only information i got online is from its similar model: http://www.dhgate.com/store/product/original-ebmpapst-r1g175-af33-06-12v-120w/202162639.html

Which tell me that its centrifugal blower wheel and it has 7 wire termination.

The thing that confuses me are the colours of wire. It has 2 red and 3 blue wires. How to make the connections to run it.

[[image: mo]

[image: s]

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyAGW.jpg)

Comment: Are all the blue|red wires connected together on the PCB?

Comment: Looks like it could have an embedded H bridge. Red/blue for power/ground, and the other two to switch the sides of the bridge high or low. Maybe. It depends what the main chip is. It could be a H bridge driver chip.

Answer (score 3):

This is made by a large German company that specialises in fans, blowers, motors and some fuel-air burners for boilers and the like.

The Finnish web site has a [model selection guide](http://www.ebmpapst.fi/fi/dat/media_manager/news/4/news-files/ebmpapstmallimer_ominaisuuserit.pdf) online. From this we can surmise the specifications.

- R : no cowling, centrifugal, one sided inlet.
- 1 : 1 HALL sensor
- G : electronicly commutated
- 175 : blade diameter (mm I expect)
- -AF : mechanical model
- 33 : electrical arrangement
- -11 : mechanical arrangement

Lots of good [manuals](http://www.ebmpapst.com/en/info-center/downloads/downloads.html#listoperatingmanuals) on the US site including a [catalogue](http://www.ebmpapst.com/media/content/info-center/downloads_10/catalogs/compactfansen2011/compactfanssingle2011/DC_centrifugal_fans_2016_01_EN.pdf) mentioning a model **R1G 120** that has connection information on a missing page 259.  It seems to be a similar fan with DC operation and elsewhere a speed sensing output and a control input are mentioned.

As mentioned in a comment if the blue and red wires are connected in the fan they are likely the power wires at perhaps 12 to 48 V (model dependant) and the other two colours are the sense and control.

**EDIT:**
Page 180 [of this catalogue](http://www.ebmpapst.com/media/content/info-center/downloads_10/catalogs/compactfansen2011/Compact_fans_for_AC_and_DC_2016_01_US.pdf) shows a connection diagram with familiar wire colours.  Later in the catalogue there are a full series of diagrams starting on page 258 as predicted in the catalogue excerpt linked above.  All that remains is to figure out the appropriate type.  From the photo it is clear that the fan is 12V nominal.

Answer (score 1):

I found this document for an equivalent model : http://img.ebmpapst.com/products/manuals/R1G175AF3308-BA-ENG.pdf

I use the search engine on this page with different mechanical arrangement : http://www.ebmpapst.com/en/products/operatinginstructions/operatinginstructions.php

Red : +12V

Blue : GND

Yellow : control (0-10V / PWM)

White : speed output (pulse)